# Scala: overcome generic type erasure for implicit resolution

Tags: scala, generics, implicit, type-erasure

Let me explain my use case first. I've a set of entities in a data store that are related to each other in a tree structure. When the version number of root node in the tree structure is increased the version numbers of related nodes must alo be increased.

Here are the set of entities

```
// ADTs
abstract class Versionable[T] { val version: T}
sealed trait PersistableEntity[I] extends Versionable[I] with Product

case class Alpha(version:Int=1) extends PersistableEntity[Int]
case class Beta(version:Int=1) extends PersistableEntity[Int]
case class Gamma(version: Int=1) extends PersistableEntity[Int]

// instances of case classes
val alpha = Alpha()
val beta1 = Beta(100)
val beta2 = Beta(200)
val gamma1 = Gamma(1000)
val gamma2 = Gamma(1100)
val gamma3 = Gamma(1200)
val gamma4 = Gamma(1300)
val gamma5 = Gamma(1400)
```

I created a type class to hold the logic that increases the version number. It's as shown below

```
sealed trait VersionGenerator[E <:PersistableEntity[_]] {
    def createNewVersion(entity:E): E
}

object VersionGenerator {
    implicit def persistableEntityVersionGenerator[E <: PersistableEntity[Int]: ClassTag]: VersionGenerator[E] =
        new VersionGenerator[E] {
            type CC = E {def copy(version: Int): E}
            override def createNewVersion(persistableEntity: E): E = persistableEntity match {
                case caseClassInstance: CC =>
                    import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
                    caseClassInstance.copy(version = persistableEntity.version+1)
                case _ => persistableEntity
            }
        }
}
```

These work fine as I was able to verify it

```
val alphaVersionGenerator = implicitly[VersionGenerator[Alpha]]
val betaVersionGenerator = implicitly[VersionGenerator[Beta]]
val gammaVersionGenerator = implicitly[VersionGenerator[Gamma]]

// Output 
alphaVersionGenerator: VersionGenerator[Alpha] = com.example.A$A107$A$A107$VersionGenerator$$anon$1@22be8030
betaVersionGenerator: VersionGenerator[Beta] = com.example.A$A107$A$A107$VersionGenerator$$anon$1@309664a7
gammaVersionGenerator: VersionGenerator[Gamma] = com.example.A$A107$A$A107$VersionGenerator$$anon$1@c1464bc
```

So far so good. I also created an implicit class and verified it as shown below

```
implicit class VersionGenerationOps[E <:PersistableEntity[_]](persistableEntity: E)(implicit evidence: VersionGenerator[E]) {
    def newVersion: E = evidence.createNewVersion(persistableEntity)
}

val updatedAlpha = alpha.newVersion
```

Here's  the output

```
updatedAlpha: Alpha = Alpha(2)
```

Similarly, the following also works

```
def createNewVersions[E <: PersistableEntity[_]](input:E*)(implicit versionGenerator: VersionGenerator[E]): Seq[E] = {
    input.map(versionGenerator.createNewVersion)
}

createNewVersions(beta1, beta2, gamma1, gamma2, gamma3, gamma4, gamma5)

// Output
res0: Seq[PersistableEntity[Int] with Serializable] = ArrayBuffer(Beta(101), Beta(201), Gamma(1001), Gamma(1101), Gamma(1201), Gamma(1301), Gamma(1401))
```

Now comes the representation of the dependency tree structure

```
// ADT
sealed trait DependencyTree[+E <:PersistableEntity[_]]
case class Branch[+E <:PersistableEntity[_]](value: E, incoming: Set[_<:DependencyTree[_<:PersistableEntity[_]]]) extends DependencyTree[E]
case class Leaf[+E <:PersistableEntity[_]](value: E) extends DependencyTree[E]
```

and the relationship between entities represented in the tree structure

```
val myDependencyTree = Branch(alpha, Set(Leaf(gamma1), Leaf(gamma2),
    Branch(beta1, Set(Leaf(gamma3), Leaf(gamma4))),
    Branch(beta2, Set(Leaf(gamma5)))
))
```

A simple traversal of the tree works just fine as shown below

```
// Simple traversal
def processDependencyTree[E <: PersistableEntity[_]](input: DependencyTree[E]): Stream[_<: PersistableEntity[_]] = {


    def processDependencyTreeBFS[T <: PersistableEntity[_]](accumulator: Stream[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]],
                                                            dependencyTree: DependencyTree[T]): Stream[_<: PersistableEntity[_]] = {
        import VersionGenerator._
        dependencyTree match {
            case node@Leaf(entity) =>
                println(s"Processing leaf: $entity")
                Stream(entity)
            case node@Branch(entity, dependencies) =>
                println(s"Processing branch: $entity")

                val processedChildren:Stream[_<: PersistableEntity[_]] = dependencies
                    .toSeq
                    .map( (dt: DependencyTree[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]]) => processDependencyTreeBFS(accumulator, dt) )
                    .reduce((first, second) => first ++ second)

                Stream.cons(entity, processedChildren)

        }
    }
    processDependencyTreeBFS(Stream.empty, input)
}

val result = processDependencyTree(myDependencyTree).toList

// Output 
Processing branch: Alpha(1)
Processing leaf: Gamma(1000)
Processing leaf: Gamma(1100)
Processing branch: Beta(100)
Processing leaf: Gamma(1200)
Processing leaf: Gamma(1300)
Processing branch: Beta(200)
Processing leaf: Gamma(1400)
result: List[PersistableEntity[_]] = List(Alpha(1), Gamma(1000), Gamma(1100), Beta(100), Gamma(1200), Gamma(1300), Beta(200), Gamma(1400))
```

Alright, now comes the problem. If I introduce an implicit parameter of type class instance, the implicit resolution fails due to type erasure.

Here's the updated code that fails

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def processDependencyTree[E <: PersistableEntity[_]](input: DependencyTree[E])
                                                    (implicit versionGenerator: VersionGenerator[E], weakTypeTag: WeakTypeTag[E]): Stream[_<: PersistableEntity[_]] = {

    def processDependencyTreeBFS[T <: PersistableEntity[_]](accumulator: Stream[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]],
                                                            dependencyTree: DependencyTree[T])
                                                           (implicit versionGenerator: VersionGenerator[T], weakTypeTag: WeakTypeTag[T]): Stream[_<: PersistableEntity[_]] = {
        import VersionGenerator._
        dependencyTree match {
            case node@Leaf(entity) =>
                println(s"Processing leaf: $entity")
                Stream(versionGenerator.createNewVersion(entity))
            case node@Branch(entity, dependencies) =>
                println(s"Processing branch: $entity")

                val processedChildren:Stream[_<: PersistableEntity[_]] = dependencies
                    .toSeq
                    .map( (dt: DependencyTree[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]]) => processDependencyTreeBFS(accumulator, dt) )
                    .reduce((first, second) => first ++ second)

                Stream.cons(versionGenerator.createNewVersion(entity), processedChildren)

        }
    }
    processDependencyTreeBFS(Stream.empty, input)
}

val result = processDependencyTree(myDependencyTree).toList
```

and the here's the error

```
Error:(84, 88) could not find implicit value for parameter versionGenerator: A$A189.this.VersionGenerator[_$20]
                    .map( (dt: DependencyTree[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]]) => processDependencyTreeBFS(accumulator, dt) )


Error:(84, 88) not enough arguments for method processDependencyTreeBFS: (implicit versionGenerator: A$A189.this.VersionGenerator[_$20], implicit weakTypeTag: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[_$20])Stream[_ <: A$A189.this.PersistableEntity[_]].
Unspecified value parameters versionGenerator, weakTypeTag.
                    .map( (dt: DependencyTree[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]]) => processDependencyTreeBFS(accumulator, dt) )


Error:(194, 88) could not find implicit value for parameter versionGenerator: inst$A$A.VersionGenerator[_$33]
                    .map( (dt: DependencyTree[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]]) => processDependencyTreeBFS(accumulator, dt) )

Error:(194, 88) not enough arguments for method processDependencyTreeBFS: (implicit versionGenerator: inst$A$A.VersionGenerator[_$33], implicit weakTypeTag: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[_$33])Stream[_ <: inst$A$A.PersistableEntity[_]].
Unspecified value parameters versionGenerator, weakTypeTag.
                    .map( (dt: DependencyTree[_ <: PersistableEntity[_]]) => processDependencyTreeBFS(accumulator, dt) )
```

Any help to fix the implicit resolution would be genuinely appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. As the type class were declared only for a specific type i.e.

```
E <: PersistableEntity[Int]
```

The implicit parameter for resolution to succeed, must also match that and not use

```
T <: PersistableEntity[_]
```